# converting time to local timezone not working with moment.js in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I am converting a timestamp on a DB object using **moment**:

```
{moment(comment.created_at).local(true).format('h:mm a')}
```

My time is outputting in UTC time because that is how it gets created in my DB.
So I am seeing '6:45 PM' for example, when I want to see the time in MY timezone (EST) or the user's relative timezone. According to the moment docs `local()` will convert to your current timezone? Calling the `local()` method as shown in my code aboven does not change the time zone. Am I using this incorrectly?

**My DB object**

```
{
  client_id: 24
  created_at: "2022-02-11 17:41:39.330443"
  id: 22
  report: "sfsf"
  report_category: "Client Assigned"
  volunteer_id: 23
}
```

Comment: what is it outputting

Comment: it outputs the UTC time that the data base entry was madee

Comment: what does the input look like

Comment: @cmgchess I updated the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your database is storing the date without an offset indicator. This means that moment cannot automatically determine the timezone. As per the [documentation on parsing dates](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/01-parsing/00-intro/):

> moment(...) is local mode. Ambiguous input (without offset) is assumed to be local time. Unambiguous input (with offset) is adjusted to local time. * **moment.utc(...) is utc mode. Ambiguous input is assumed to be UTC.**

So if you know your input is UTC and you know it won't have an offset indicator, use `moment.utc()` instead of `moment()`.

Furthermore, you don't want to use `local(true)`, since passing in "true" will only change the timezone on the object without changing the time (see the [documentation](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/07-local/)). So you're left with:

```
{moment.utc(comment.created_at).local().format('h:mm a')}
```

Comment: After applying the above changes I still do not see the time being converted to my local timezone

Comment: My mistake, I didn't look closely enough at the documentation on [`local()`](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/07-local/). I've updated my answer, but I'm glad someone else was able to sort out your issue!

Comment: nice this looks shorter and cleaner

Answer (score 1):

I converted your DB timestamp into ISO format and then passed into your implementation

```js
let t = "2022-02-11 17:41:39.330443"

let utcISOTimestamp = moment.utc(t).toDate()
console.log(utcISOTimestamp)

//let res = moment(utcISOTimestamp).local(true).format('h:mm a');
let res = moment(moment.utc(t).toDate()).local(true).format('h:mm a');

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is working nicely!

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
moment.utc('2022-02-11 17:41:39').local().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```